# 100% packet loss banana pi m2 zero, using an armbian release

Tags: sshd, armbian, bananapi

I've cracked my head on this for a while. I can't ssh into my banana pi m2 zero(I don't have a mini-usb cord, I'm trying to boot wirelessly for the first time). I get 100% packet loss every time I try to ping it. I know it connected to the wifi. I'm using this armbian release:
https://www.armbian.com/banana-pi-m2-plus/

Here's what I've done:

1. I made a blank ssh file in /boot
2. In the sshd_config file I set PermitRootLogin and PasswordAuthentication to yes
3. I added a before.rules file in etc/ufw/ it has this inside:

```
# Allow all incoming traffic
-A ufw-before-input -j ACCEPT

# Allow all outgoing traffic
-A ufw-before-output -j ACCEPT

# Allow all forwarded traffic
-A ufw-before-forward -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH connections
-A ufw-before-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

4. I made sure no other machine is using port 22
5. sudo systemctl start ssh
6. When I do nmap , I get:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-01-03 19:25 EST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 5.03 seconds
```

P.S.: I've been editing the OS with a linux vm and I remember yesterday I was able to ping it with no packet loss(I think) but couldn't ssh into it. I don't remember what I did to break it though :P What I listed is what I currently did to the

Comment: What is the point of step 4? An open port 22 on machine B has no bearing on machine A's ability to accept an ssh connection. After step 5, what is the result of `sudo systemctl status ssh`? Does ssh work if you disable ufw?

Comment: @JaromandaX I wasn't sure about step 4, though I did it anyways just in case. Also, apparently debian uses ip tables instead of ufw by default. I don't remember much of the systemctl, all I remember is that it said successfully something

Comment: so, did you try disabling ufw and did you try running `sudo systemctl status ssh`